# Xcode error: Failed to parse IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: Could not parse version component from: '0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, xcode10.3

I am trying to run my app on iOS version 12.3.1 iPad. It's run well for the first time but after stopping the build and restart the process my build always failed with an error?

> error: Failed to parse IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: Could not parse version component from: '0'

Please help me. I am not finding any solution related to my problem on the internet.

**Tired solution:**

- Trying on the simulators (not work)
- My iPhone (not work)
- Restarting Xcode (not work)
- Restarting Macbook (not work)

Any help will be appreciated.